# Using AppEngine-MapReduce on Google App Engine, what is the easiest way to analyze entities for a specific date range?

Tags: google-app-engine, mapreduce

I am trying to use AppEngine-MapReduce. I understand how to perform an operation over all entities of some entity_kind, but what is the easiest way to only operate on entities over a data range when the entity has a date attribute? Is there a simple way to pass parameters to the mapper?

For example, what if I only wanted to delete entities where:

```
entity.created >= start and entity.created < stop

class Entity(db.Model):
  created = db.DateTimeProperty()

from mapreduce import operation as op
def process(entity):
  yield op.db.Delete(entity)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently there's no way to iterate over a query in a mapreduce - you have to iterate over every entity of the given kind. Instead, you should apply the filter in the map function, and only delete entities that match.

Comment: What if I created a simple model called DateRange where each entity had DateRange.start and DateRange.stop? Then could I perform map reduce across all DateRange entities and fetch my other models from entity.start to entity.stop. For example:  def process(entity): someEntities = SomeModel.all().filter('date >= ', entity.start).filter('date < ', entity.stop)  It seems like this would be the easiest way to look at specific date ranges using the current implementation. Thanks in advance Nick.

Comment: Sure, but then you're replicating most of mapreduce's sharding logic to generate your date ranges. If you just want to delete records matching a certain criteria, though, you may want to look into using cursors in conjunction with key_only queries and the task queue.

Comment: I agree. Deleting records was just a simple example to see if I could perform operations over specific date ranges rather than over all entities.

Comment: This answer is no longer accurate, since App Engine 1.9.0 SDK. Please see: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/dataprocessing/ (Java) and https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/dataprocessing/ (Python).

Answer (score 0):

Since [commit324](http://code.google.com/p/appengine-mapreduce/source/detail?spec=svn329&r=324) it is possible to use limited query filters as input.

If that will not let you do what you want there is an [small extension](https://github.com/lukmdo/appengine-mapreduce-utils) you might want to try.